# perimeter of a triangle in C

Tags: c

so i received more missions in C as we are at home from school and it's pain, because homeschooling is only about googling a lot. Anyway, I should somehow print the perimeter of triangle using functions.

```
bool platny(double a, double b, double c) {
  return a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a;
}

void printPlatny(double a, double b, double c) {
  bool isValid = platny(a, b, c);
  if (isValid) {
    printf("Trojuhelnik (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f) je platny\n", a, b, c);
  } else {
    printf("Trojuhelnik (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f) neni platny\n", a, b, c);
  }
}
```

This part of code above works as something, whats trying to find, if the triange(trojuhelnik) even exists = is valid(platny). 
And there is 0 problems with this part, that's why I thought even the perimeter and area will be as simple as this part. Well, the next part of code is the perimeter.

```
double obvodT;
double obvod(double a, double b, double c){
    obvodT = (a+b+c);
    return obvodT;
}


void printObvod(double a, double b, double c){
    bool isValid = platny(a,b,c);

    if(isValid){
        printf("Trojuhelnik ma obvod %.2f \n", obvodT);
    }
    else {
        printf("Trojuhelnik (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f) neni platny\n", a, b, c);
    }
}
```

but somehow, all the time i try to printObvod(2,2,3) f.e., it prints that triangle's perimeter is 0.00. I guess I have something wrong with the whole thing, but why, shouldn't it work as the first part? What do you recommend to change or delete? Thanks for answers and helping me with progress at school. 
*PERIMETER ANSWERED*

Since the perimeter is done, I thought the area of triangle will be easy and same as the perimeter. So I did copy the code, change a little bit to this form

```
    double obsah(double podstava,double vyska){
    return ((1/2)*(podstava*vyska));
}

void printObsah(double podstava, double vyska){
    printf("Obsah trojuhelniku je %.2f \n", obsah(podstava,vyska));
}
```

"podstava" stands for *a* and "vyska" is height of the triangle. I gues mathematically it's correct. I have no idea what I'm missing this time, I should take few minutes off the computer .. *DONE*

Comment: You have not called the function `obvod()` so *perimeter* has not been calculated.

Comment: I see it now. ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not call `obvod` function here

```
printf("Trojuhelnik ma obvod %.2f \n", obvodT);
```

Change it to

```
printf("Trojuhelnik ma obvod %.2f \n", obvod(a,b,c));
```

Also it would be better to change this code

```
double obvodT;
double obvod(double a, double b, double c){
    obvodT = (a+b+c);
    return obvodT;
}
```

To this

```
double obvod(double a, double b, double c){
    return (a+b+c);
}
```

`obvodT` is not needed. Also try to avoid using gobal variables this way.

You result was `0.00` since global variables initialized to 0 and you did not called your function to change its value.

Comment: Perhaps point out that `double obvodT;` is a global, and the poor practice hid the reason for the error?

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought I would put the value into the variable and it will be ready to be used. That's why i tried to return obvodT. I was sure inside the variable will be stored "a+b+c"

Comment: `double obvodT;` should really be a **local** variable inside the function.

Comment: I guess with the triangle content it will be the same? I'll just make double content(double a, double height) and return will be 1/2*a*height. am i right?

Comment: @TomášJahoda programmatically yes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Eraklon's answer - don't use the `obvod()` function to set a global variable. Instead, just have it return the computed value; that's quite enough.